# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception with HashMap in android

Tags: java, arrays, listview, hashmap

having a problem with this bit of code below.
What it's supposed to do is take the numbers in arrDBNumbers and use those numbers to fill listview with the 6 different images. arrDBNumbers is full, and going through int a - f they get filled, but at

```
hm.put("flag1", Integer.toString(balls[a]) );
```

everything hangs???? it will not go past this and I get an Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception

```
    public class ResLotto extends Activity {



int[][] arrDBNumbers = new int[100][8];
String[] arrDBNumbersS = new String[60];
String st0, st1, st2, st3, st4, st5, st6, st7, st8, st9, st10, st11, st12, st13, st14, st15, st16, st17, st18, st19, st20, st21, st22, st23, st24, st25, st26, st27, st28, st29;
private DownloadWebPageTask mTask = null;
private final static String Array="LottoArray.txt"; 
final Context context = this;
int[] balls = new int[]{R.drawable.b1, R.drawable.b2, R.drawable.b3, R.drawable.b4, R.drawable.b5, R.drawable.b6, R.drawable.b7, R.drawable.b8, R.drawable.b9,
R.drawable.b10, R.drawable.b11, R.drawable.b12, R.drawable.b13, R.drawable.b14, R.drawable.b15, R.drawable.b16, R.drawable.b17, R.drawable.b18, R.drawable.b19,
R.drawable.b20, R.drawable.b21, R.drawable.b22, R.drawable.b23, R.drawable.b24, R.drawable.b25, R.drawable.b26, R.drawable.b27, R.drawable.b28, R.drawable.b29,
R.drawable.b30, R.drawable.b31, R.drawable.b32, R.drawable.b33, R.drawable.b34, R.drawable.b35, R.drawable.b36, R.drawable.b37, R.drawable.b38, R.drawable.b39,
R.drawable.b40, R.drawable.b41, R.drawable.b42, R.drawable.b43, R.drawable.b44, R.drawable.b45, R.drawable.b46, R.drawable.b47, R.drawable.b48, R.drawable.b49,
};
int a = 0;
int b = 0; 
int c = 0;
int d = 0;
int e = 0;
int f = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_res_lotto);
    RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.baseLayer);
    rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    if ( customTitleSupported ) {
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
    }
    final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);

    File fileArray = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(Array);
    if(fileArray.exists()) { 
        try {
            InputStream in=openFileInput(Array);            
            if (in!=null) {
                InputStreamReader tmp=new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(tmp);
                String str;
                while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
                        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){                            
                            arrDBNumbers[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(str);
                            str = reader.readLine();    
                        }
                    }
                }   
                in.close();     
            }
        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast
            .makeText(this, "Error opening database file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }   

        try {
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(String.valueOf(arrDBNumbers[0][0]));
            if (buf.length() == 7)
                buf.insert(0, "0");
            buf.insert(4, "/");
            buf.insert(2, "/");
            myTitleText.setText("Lotto, Last updated: " + buf);
            myTitleText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast
            .makeText(this, "Error reading date to title", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
        }
        loadListBox();

    }   
    else if (!(fileArray.exists())){
        myTitleText.setText("Lotto, Last updated: Never");
        myTitleText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("First time use!");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Data will now be downloaded to populate grid");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setNegativeButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
                checkconnection();

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}

private void loadListBox(){


    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();     
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        a = arrDBNumbers[i][1];
        b = arrDBNumbers[i][2];
        c = arrDBNumbers[i][3];
        d = arrDBNumbers[i][4];
        e = arrDBNumbers[i][5];
        f = arrDBNumbers[i][6];


        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();

        hm.put("flag1", Integer.toString(balls[a]) ); 
        hm.put("flag2", Integer.toString(balls[b]) ); 
        hm.put("flag3", Integer.toString(balls[c]) ); 
        hm.put("flag4", Integer.toString(balls[d]) ); 
        hm.put("flag5", Integer.toString(balls[e]) ); 
        hm.put("flag6", Integer.toString(balls[f]) );            
        aList.add(hm);        
    }
    String[] from = { "flag1","flag2","flag3","flag4","flag5","flag6" };

    int[] to = { R.id.ivB1,R.id.ivB2,R.id.ivB3,R.id.ivB4,R.id.ivB5,R.id.ivB6};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.results_row, from, to);
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);  
}
```

the code below works and puts 6 images in a listview. but their all the same images 1 - 6 repeated.

```
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();     
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){        

        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();

        hm.put("flag1", Integer.toString(balls[1]) ); 
        hm.put("flag2", Integer.toString(balls[2]) ); 
        hm.put("flag3", Integer.toString(balls[3]) ); 
        hm.put("flag4", Integer.toString(balls[4]) ); 
        hm.put("flag5", Integer.toString(balls[5]) ); 
        hm.put("flag6", Integer.toString(balls[6]) );            
        aList.add(hm);        
    }
    String[] from = { "flag1","flag2","flag3","flag4","flag5","flag6" };

    int[] to = { R.id.ivB1,R.id.ivB2,R.id.ivB3,R.id.ivB4,R.id.ivB5,R.id.ivB6};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.results_row, from, to);
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

anybody know what is going wrong?
I've tried

```
        hm.put("flag1", String.valueOf(balls[a]) );
        hm.put("flag1", balls[a].toString() );
```

Thanks in advance T

Comment: Which line is failing? And where are you initializing `arrDBNumbers` and `balls`?

Comment: Hi, hm.put("flag1", Integer.toString(balls[a]) ); fails. All code that initializes them is working and they are filled.

Comment: And what is the value of `a` at that line? And what's the size of `balls`? There's far too much you haven't told us. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: a is 23, and balls goes all the way to 50

Comment: That seems unlikely to me, to be honest. Can you produce a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem? Currently we'd just be guessing.

Comment: You say you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException - can you post the stack trace? It should show the index and size.

Comment: You have only 49 drawable ids in `balls` table, but you want 50.

Comment: sorry n00bi not to sure how to do that. Is it the LogCat window?

Comment: @Grzegorz sorry meant to say 49